# what is sound channels and what is it all?

Tags: audio

while downloading a video or a movie or watching a tv show  i find some information about the sound using numbers of channels

what is it exactly and how many of it exists?

i only know those

```
2.0
2.1
5.1
7.1
```

is those are all the existing sound channels?

i just want to know what is all the existing channels and where/how do they work exactly when i download and watch my videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never have more channels than you have physical speakers.

the .X refers to subwoofers - they play lower frequency sounds and add base.

2.0 is 2 speakers (front left and right), and 2.1 adds a woofer.

5.1 is center, front left and right, and rear left and right. 7.1 adds left and right, though apparently the geometry of the rear speakers.

More or less, if you have more channels than speakers or vice versa, you can downmix. That said, with modern technology - like dolby athmos (and there's a home varient of it), and software, you can actually have an arbitrary number of speakers in arbitrary positions. Athmos for example has 24.1.10 support - with the last 10 being *ceiling speakers*.

Practically speaking - if you play 7.1 audio in with 2.0 speakers - the low frequencies don't get cut by the crossovers (a series of audio filters) and your audio plays as 2.0. With 2.1, the 7 channels get downmixed to 2.

Conversely if you play 2.0 audio in 7.1 speakers you'd either use 2 speakers or split the 7 speakers into left and right channels, depending on the processing.

Comment: Technically, with "virtual surround" (usually with a good HRTF) you can downmix many channels into a few while preserving the feeling of directionality. Usually done with headphones, though, not speakers. Atmos can do something similar.